# query most recent record only on a 1-to-many join

Tags: postgresql

I'm working on a project where I'm pulling users and their latest blog post. The software we have stores a version ID similar to drupal. I'm hitting many errors with the query though. I'm used to writing MySQL queries, and I thought this would work, but Postegres is giving me issues.

```
Users Table:
id
name
...

Posts Table:
id
authorID
versoinID
title
content
.....

SELECT u.id, u.name, p.id, p.versionID p.title FROM Users u LEFT OUTER JOIN Posts p on u.id = p.authorID GROUP BY u.id ORDER BY versionID DESC
```

This throws the error: column "dcr2.vid" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

I'd really like to get the results along the lines of

```
1 | John | 101 | 1 | How to write Queries
2 | James | 102 | 1 | Trapped on an island
```

Where the results reflect the most recent blog version. This is something I believe I've done in MySQL, but I'm getting errors with Postegres. Any suggestions?

Comment: Your missing a comma in your query. Not exactly sure if that will solve the problem though: `SELECT u.id, u.name, p.id, p.versionID, p.title`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use windowing functions in Postgres for this:

```
SELECT *
FROM
    (
        SELECT u.id,
            u.NAME,
            p.id,
            p.versionID,
            p.title,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY u.id ORDER BY p.versionID DESC) as versionRAnk
        FROM Users u
        LEFT JOIN Posts p
            ON u.id = p.authorID
    )rankQuery
WHERE rankQuery.versionRank = 1
```

This has your original query (without the GROUP and ORDER BY bits) as the subquery. Also in the subquery is a windowing function that will rank, for each `userid`, the record by `p.versionID`. Because it's descending, the highest `VersionID` will get the `ROW_NUMBER` of `1`. The outer query just selects everything and only keeps records that were ranked `1`.

Comment: This is a new approach to me for sure. The only issue I see though is one that I didn't explain all that well. Later versions are going to be the most recent. In your example, I see how this works taking only the version at 1, but what if I need only the highest version per post id, which typically won't be consistent across all posts being queried?

Comment: So, in that scenario, would you want to see multiple post id's per person? Like John would show Post Id's 1, 2, 3, and 4. I assume then that each Post id might have multiple versions, from which you would want the latest? If that's the case, then add `p.id` into the `PARTITION BY` part of the statement. like `.. ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY u.id, p.id ORDER BY p.versionID DESC) ... `.  Then it will partition by person and post, and then rank the versions descending.

Comment: Great solution. I'm finding some weird cross over with sql between MySQL and Postgres, but luckily, Postgres has an awesome community behind it to help me fill in those gaps.